# How to give vertical margins inside a minipage

Tags: minipage

I want to give top and bottom margins inside minipages and tried using `\vspace` as shown below.

But this approach causes a pseudo line below the in-minipage text when the text width is almost fit to the minipage width. (Please compare the two minipages below)

Is there a better approach that prevents this issue?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

When "vspace" is not inserted:

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2
    \end{minipage}
}

\vspace{30pt}

When "vspace" is inserted to give vertical margin in the minipage:

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
    \vspace{2pt}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2
    \vspace{2pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when I run your example, the second one the text is on two lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code does not show the effect that you ask about, I changed the minipage width in the example below so the second example shows the problem.

[image]

The spurious white line is not caused by the `\vspace` but by the extra inter-word space that you added. You can avoid adding the space by commenting out the end of line or (better) always add a blank line before a `\vspace` so that it is added in vertical mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

When "vspace" is not inserted:

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2
    \end{minipage}
}

\vspace{30pt}

When "vspace" is inserted to give vertical margin in the minipage:

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.55cm}
    \vspace{2pt}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2
    \vspace{2pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.55cm}
    \vspace{2pt}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2%
    \vspace{2pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{2.55cm}
    \vspace{2pt}
        \raggedright
        AAA CD/ BB-2

    \vspace{2pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks!